# How do I uninstall Nvidia drivers from Zorin 16?

Tags: drivers

When I installed Zorin 16, I mistakenly installed the Nvidia drivers. My laptop only has AMD Radeon graphics. The Nvidia drivers are causing glitches on my display like screen flickering. Is there any way for me to uninstall these drivers without having to install Zorin again?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the nvidia related installed packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

Then assume the list is oki just remove them:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Comment: I don't appear to have any nvidia drivers. I know I chose the nvidia install. Strange. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you really installed the nvidia stuff you shouold have nvidia-settings installed. Also if the answeer did solve your problem please mark it as solution so other people can take advantage of it.